# QByteArray непонятная 3 в начале массива

Tags: c++, qt5

Мне нужно передавать данные в HEX на удаленное устройство.
Если я пишу:

```
QByteArray tmp = QByteArray::number(0);
qDebug() << tmp.toHex(); //Результат 30

QByteArray tmp2 = QByteArray::fromHex("5");
qDebug() << tmp2.toHex();   //Результат 05 - Как нужно.

//Так же пробовал пример из Qt
int n = 63;
QByteArray::number(n);              // returns "63"
QByteArray::number(n, 16);          // returns "3f"
QByteArray::number(n, 16).toUpper();  // returns "3F"
```

Я просто что-то не понимаю в его работе. Задача простая, посылать по TCP HEX значения. Откуда берется в начале 3 и как от неё избавиться.

Comment: `63` - это `3f` в hex

Comment: в Qt примере - это понятно, но если изменить 63 например на 22, то результат будет не 16.

Comment: если  QByteArray::number возвращает строку, то избавляться от первого символа является тривиальной задачей. Это даже не задача

Comment: А какой он будет, если не 16?

Comment: Уточните что вы понимаете под "данные в HEX"

Answer (score 0):

```
QByteArray::number(int n, int base = 10)
```

Возвращает массив байтов, содержащий !СТРОКУ!, эквивалентную номеру n базовой базе (по умолчанию 10). Базой может быть любое значение от 2 до 36.

Соответственно `QByteArray tmp = QByteArray::number(0);` вернет строку, содержащую ноль, символ "0" имеет код 48(0x30)

Вот это `QByteArray tmp2 = QByteArray::fromHex("5");` в свою очередь вернет массив, содержащий декодированное значение из hex-строки. Поскольку у вас указано "5", то оно декодируется как один байт 5(0х05)

`QByteArray::number(63);` - вернет СТРОКУ "63", или два байта 0х36 0х33
`QByteArray::number(63, 16);` - вернет СТРОКУ "3f", или два байта 0х33 0х66

Если вам надо просто добавлять байты в сетевую посылку, то используйте обычный append(unsigned char)